# Question about correspondence theorem for rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

For the following question:

Let $K$ be an ideal in ring $R$.  Prove that every ideal in the quotient ring $\frac{R}{K}$ is of the form $\frac{I}{K}$ for some ideal $I$ in $R$.

I don't understand what I am suppose to prove here.  Am I suppose to do the following:  Suppose $M$ is an ideal in $\frac{R}{K}$, then $M=\frac{I}{K}$
There is a hint which ask the reader to use the following two exercises which I have already done.  I don't know how to make use of them since the question sound very similar to question 1 in the hint.  I am having trouble translating the question into proper math notation.

1. Let $I$ and $K$ be ideals in a ring $R$, with $K\subset I$.  Prove that $\frac{I}{K}=\{a+K:a\in I\}$ is an ideal in the quotient ring $\frac{R}{K}$
2. Let $f:R\rightarrow S$ be a homomorphism of rings. If $J$ is an ideal in $S$ and $I=\{r\in R: f(r)\in J\}$, prove that $I$ is an ideal in $R$ that contains the kernel of $f$ 
   Thank you in advance.

Comment: You're being asked to prove that every ideal of the quotient ring corresponds to an ideal $K \subseteq I \subseteq R$, and that the ideal in the quotient ring is in fact the quotient of $I$.  It's conceivable that there are ideals of $R/K$ that don't have a corresponding ideal in $R$ that contains $K$, so there really is something to prove here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the homomorphism $f:R \to R/K$. Using the second exercise you get that for each ideal $J \subset R/K$ there is an ideal $I \subset R$ with $\ker(f) = K\subset I$ and $f(I) = J$.

From the first exercise, you know that $I/K$ is an ideal of $R/K$ if $K\subset I$ and $I\subset R$ ideal. Now you can use the above morphism to show that each $J\subset R/K$ ideal has such a representation $J=I/K$.

How? Start with an arbitrary ideal $J \subset R/K$. Above homomorphism yields an ideal $I\subset R$ with $f(I)=J$. But how does $f(I)$ look like? This is nothing else than $f(I) = I/K = \{a + K | a \in I\}$, because $f$ is defined this way. This means you have $f(I) = I/K = J$. Since $J$ was arbitrary you have found a representation of $J$ of the form $I/K$.

Comment: Can I ask why do I have to look at the homomorphism $f:R\rightarrow \frac{R}{K}$. Is just I reread the question a dozen of times and I try to match some way the question is phrased to the hints.

Comment: Does this answer explain the solution a bit better? Just tell me if I should clarify something

Comment: how did you arrive at the homomorphism from the two hints.  I am having trouble seeing that.  Maybe I am suppose to figure out how to $S$  with  quotient ring $R/K$ and $I$ with $I/K$ in question 2. Also, why is this call a correspondence theorem?  thanks

Comment: You can not immediately arrive with that homomorphism. However as you have two rings $R$, $R/K$ to consider this is the only ring homomorphism that makes sense to me and that immediately popped up into my mind.

Comment: Correspondence theorem comes from the $1$-to-$1$ correspondence between ideals $I\subset R$ and ideals $I/K \subset R/K$

Comment: does this mean the question can be rephrase as if we have ring $R$ and ideal $I$ in $R$, then the ideal of $R/K$ is $I/K$ and vice versa?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124281/discussion-between-legnaib-and-seth-mai).

Comment: there is a second part of the exercise to this question which ask the reader to show:  If $f:R\rightarrow S$ is a surjective homomorphism of rings with kernel $K$, prove that there is a bijective function from the set of all ideals of $S$ to the set of all ideals of $R$ that contains $K$.  So the bijective function portion of the question comes next.  I did not know I can just set up a ring homomorphism the way you suggested since it was not given in the question.

Comment: The homomorphism theorem can help you in such cases. However, take a look at your exercise 2. That is almost the exact same statement: It already says that you can go from ideals of $S$ to ideals of $R$. Only difference: $f$ is surjective and this is necessary that the other way works: Given an $I$ in $R$ with $I\subset K$ we can get an ideal $J \subset S$, so we can also go from ideals of $R$ to ideals of $S$ (without subjectivity that wouldn't be possible)

Comment: thank you so much for the clarification.